# text search spanning all collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to do text search spanning all collections
I have successfully used queries like these below on individual collections

```
db.mycollectionname.find({$text:{ $search : "mytextstring"}})
```

but now i want something that would return results from multiple collections at once. I don't want to handle this at application level to reduce network calls to db.

What are my options? i don't think aggregate or map reduce would work for me as they seem something like group by(Please correct me if I am wrong). What I want is Union All kind of functionality. Ideally I would not like to hard code collection names too. Query should just do text search on all collections.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchAll(query,fields,sort) {
    var all = db.getCollectionNames();
    var results = [];
    for (var i in all) {
        var coll = all[i];
        if (coll == "system.indexes") continue;
        db[coll].find(query,fields).sort(sort).forEach(
            function (rec) {results.push(rec);} );
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me except that i used listCollections method since getCollectionNames ould not work for me. However here we are making multiple network calls to mongo.. first to get list of all collections and then looping through all and doing a find. IS there a way I can get just all results in just one call